# Switch order of hyphenated words

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the best way to parse a list of hyphenated words and return the beginning and end words switched?

Input:

```
spider-man
wonder-woman
```

Output:

```
man-spider
woman-wonder
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of asking us for code, you need to research, then try, then, when you have a problem, present the minimal code you've written to solve the problem, some input and output data, and we'll help you. As is, we can't tell if you tried, and it looks like you're asking us to write code for you, which is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could split it and then reverse it.

```
"spider-man".split('-').reverse.join('-')
 #=> "man-spider"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could go with regex

```
"spider-man".gsub(/^(.+)-(.+)$/, '\2-\1')
#=> "man-spider"
```

And it will be as twice as slower than @rohit89 solution ;)

Comment: So you will be tapping your fingers waiting for it to finish? There's something about splitting, processing, joining that grates. I suppose it  reads better, but I still prefer to work on the string directly, as you've done.

Comment: If you want to make benchmarks, perhaps using `([^-]*)` in place of the first `(.+)` is faster (not tested). you can also use `sub` instead of `gsub`

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think split solution is much more idiomatic Ruby. In terms of speed one could choose something like `pos = str.index("-"); str[pos+1..-1] + "-" + str[0...pos]`. And also when you work with strings directly you always should be aware of its mutable nature.

Comment: @Casimir et Hippolyte I am not sure if `([^-]*)` will work here

Comment: Regex is about 3x slower than using the methods.

Comment: @theTinMan in my benchmarks it was about 2.3x slower so I just rounded it down

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split), [`reverse`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-reverse), and  [`join`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-join)

```
words = ['spider-man', 'super-woman']

words.map do |word|
  word.split('-').reverse.join('-')
end

# => ['man-spider', woman-super']
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's benchmark time:

```
require 'fruity'

STR = 'spider-man'

compare do
  split_reverse_join {STR.split('-').reverse.join('-') }
  regex { STR.gsub(/^(.+)-(.+)$/, '\2-\1') }
end

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> split_reverse_join is faster than regex by 3x ± 0.1
```

Comparing minor changes to the pattern:

```
require 'fruity'

STR = 'spider-man'

compare do
  regex1 { STR.gsub(/^(.+)-(.+)$/, '\2-\1') }
  regex2 { STR.gsub(/^([^-]*)-(.+)$/, '\2-\1') }
end
# >> Running each test 1024 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> regex1 is similar to regex2
```

Comparing `gsub` to `sub`:

```
compare do
  gsub_regex { STR.gsub(/^(.+)-(.+)$/, '\2-\1') }
  sub_regex { STR.sub(/^(.+)-(.+)$/, '\2-\1') }
end
# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> sub_regex is faster than gsub_regex by 70.0% ± 10.0%
```

`sub` is always faster than `gsub` since it'll bail out after the first search hit, instead of looking for additional hits.

---

> The fastest will be the ugliest one. `pos = str.index("-"); str[pos+1..-1] + "-" + str[0...pos]`

```
compare do
  split_reverse_join {STR.split('-').reverse.join('-') }
  regex { STR.gsub(/^(.+)-(.+)$/, '\2-\1') }
  pos {
    pos = STR.index("-")
    STR[pos+1..-1] + "-" + STR[0...pos]   
  }
end

# >> Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 1 second.
# >> pos is faster than split_reverse_join by 19.999999999999996% ± 10.0%
# >> split_reverse_join is faster than regex by 3x ± 0.1
```

Comment: The fastest will be the ugliest one. `pos = str.index("-"); str[pos+1..-1] + "-" + str[0...pos]`

Comment: I made the test several times and I obtain very erratic results between 60% and 3x (but always in favor of the split/join approach).

Comment: I can't really comment on that since I don't know how you did the benchmark. I use Fruity almost exclusively now as it's very consistent in its testing and reporting. Running multiple tests returns the above results most often.

Comment: After several tests with `sub`, it seems that writing `(.*)-` is faster (or equal) than `^([^-]*)-`. Conclusion: perhaps using `(.*)literal` allows an internal optimisation (like a quick search algorithm) that the more descriptive/hand-driven `^([^-]*)literal` forbids (other possibility the (small) difference is only due to the pattern compilation time).

Comment: amazing analysis, thank you so much for this